# How to test SAP HTTP Content Server API 'docGet' API from SAP GUI

Tags: sap-basis

I am new to this, and while I was exploring this documentation of SAP HTTP Content Server Interface where we have 'docGet' API to get archived file details based on 'documentId' of archived object, which will eventually return multipart/form-data for given documentId.

What I am not getting is how this API is getting called from SAP GUI, to be precise.. I need to know at which page or using transaction code we will get call to this API as per our action in SAP GUI.

Please help me with this concern or any direction would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Abhishek

Comment: I guess you are talking about this link to "Function: docGet" of "SAP Content Server HTTP 4.5 Interface": https://help.sap.com/docs/search?q=Function%3A%20docGet